# Three Tables Horizontal

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm creating a page that needs three tables placed horizontally.
I tried two first using:

```
#table_one {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#table_two {
position:relative;
display: block;
}
```

And it worked. I wanted to add another table so I tried:

```
#table_one {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#table_two {
position:relative;
display: block;

#table_three {
position:relative;
float: right;
}
```

But that third table appears below the two tables, placed itself on the right, and it expands itself vertically it even got out of my page background.

Comment: Where is the HTML that holds your tables? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `float:left/right` use inline layout for the block elements (like [**display:inline-block**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwUZL/) or [**display:table-cell**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwUZL/1/))

Comment: It works man thanks. but there's one thing - the table_one's height is 20%, table_two 50%, and table_three is 20% so as you can see the middle one is higher than the other two. But the table_two expands vertically via upward direction not downward.If I keep putting things on table_two, it will grow up higher and higher. How can I make this expands downward so that the other two table stays on top not on the ground?

Comment: @RunCode : Apply `vertical-align:top` to the table element .[__Example__](http://jsfiddle.net/xwUZL/2/)